Generate Test Cafe Studio Report
After executing a test in studio, I am able to click on the export report Icon but it creates a json report which is not readable. What recommendation do you have that can help generate a human readable report from Studio?

TestCafe Studio allows you to export a report to an archive file. This archive will include the serialized report in the selected format.
You can also try to find a suitable format and add it to TestCafe Studio. You can find more details here: Get More Report Formats
